# How to return a list as dictionary using FastAPI and Pydantic model?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm using FastAPI and sqlalchemy.

This how I get data from database:

```json
article = {
    "title": "For example Title",
    "description": "for example Description",
    "translation": [
        {"id": 1, "lang": "ar", "title": "ar title"},
        {"id": 2, "lang": "fr", "title": "fr title"},
        {"id": 3, "lang": "de", "title": "de title"},
    ],
}
```

and this how I want to make a response with above data:

```json
article = {
    "title": "For example Title",
    "description": "for example Description",
    "translation": {
        "ar": {"id": 1, "title": "ar title"},
        "fr": {"id": 2, "title": "fr title"},
        "de": {"id": 3, "title": "de title"},
    }
}
```

i've converted list from database to dict for translations

What is the best way to describe the pydantic scehma for translation and every article contain different number of translation for articles?

Current Schema

```py
class Article(BaseModel):
    title: str
    description: str 
    translations: list[trans]
```

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary comprehension from [@Marcin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76084572) is of course the right way to transform the original data and the proposed model structure is correct.

But you can put that transformation logic inside of a [`pre=True` field validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators) for `translations`:

```py
from collections.abc import Mapping
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Translation(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str


class Article(BaseModel):
    title: str
    description: str
    translations: dict[str, Translation]

    @validator("translations", pre=True)
    def non_mapping_to_dictionary(cls, v: Any) -> Any:
        if isinstance(v, Mapping):
            return v  # already in correct form
        return {
            translation["lang"]: {
                "id": translation["id"],
                "title": translation["title"],
            }
            for translation in v
        }
```

Then you can initialize `Article` both with already *correct* `translations` data as well as with the *to-be-transformed* list-form you get from the database:

```py
test_data = {
    "title": "For example Title",
    "description": "for example Description",
    "translations": [  # needs to be transformed
        {"id": 1, "lang": "ar", "title": "ar title"},
        {"id": 2, "lang": "fr", "title": "fr title"},
        {"id": 3, "lang": "de", "title": "de title"},
    ],
}
print(Article(**test_data).json(indent=4))

test_data["translations"] = {  # already correct
    "ua": {"id": 4, "title": "ua title"},
    "ru": {"id": 5, "title": "ru title"},
    "en": {"id": 6, "title": "en title"},
}
print(Article(**test_data).json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "title": "For example Title",
    "description": "for example Description",
    "translations": {
        "ar": {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "ar title"
        },
        "fr": {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "fr title"
        },
        "de": {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "de title"
        }
    }
}
```

```json
{
    "title": "For example Title",
    "description": "for example Description",
    "translations": {
        "ua": {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "ua title"
        },
        "ru": {
            "id": 5,
            "title": "ru title"
        },
        "en": {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "en title"
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to be extra clean about this, you should consider adding a few `try`-`except`-blocks to/around that loop to facilitate proper validation errors. Cases such as the value not being an iterable at all, an element from it not being a mapping at all, or one of the mappings not having a necessary key, would all be examples of invalid structure that you may or may not want to provide specific error messages for. But that is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

First, separate the translaction entity in your schema:

```
class Translation(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str

class Article(BaseModel):
    title: str
    description: str
    translations: Dict[str, Translation]
```

Once that is done you need to build expected data structure from what you have now:

```py
translations_dict = {t["lang"]: {"id": t["id"], "title": t["title"]} for t in db_translations}

article_data = {
    "title": "For example Title",
    "description": "for example Description",
    "translations": translations_dict,
}

article = Article(**article_data)
```